# Any skilled pilots? Explain how a craft flies over the curve of the earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, pressure, aircraft

So, flat earthers believe that there are no adjustments, whether in manual or autopilot, to maintain level flight over curved surface such as earth. But, altitude is determined by barometric pressure (BP) at sea level and that info translates to a plane enabling it to follow the curve of earth. I guess my question is, how? Are the various BP along the route always going  to be greater than the one you're at thereby causing the plane to auto adjust to maintain the altitude?

Comment: Your question about pressure along the route isn't clear to me.  Can you be more specific about what you are asking?

Answer (score 3):

Commercial aircraft spend most of their time following [*flight levels*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_level).

Every commercial aircraft is equipped with a [*pressure altimeter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altimeter), which gives an an accurate reading of the aircraft's elevation above sea-level *IF* it is adjusted for the current barometer reading on the ground beneath.

At take-off, and at landing, they adjust their altimeter to the same setting as an altimeter on the ground at the airport that is continually adjusted to show the known field elevation. But in-between airports, they they set the altimeter to a *standard* pressure setting, 1013.25 hPa (29.92 inHg), and then they maintain a constant *indicated altitude,* as directed by the flight controllers.

If they fly over an area where the barometric pressure is higher than the standard pressure, then their *true elevation* (i.e., height above sea-level) will be greater than what their altimeter indicates. If they fly over an area of lower-than-standard pressure, then their true elevation will be less. But the important thing is, *all* of the aircraft in the vicinity will be flying higher or lower by the same amount. So if the air traffic controllers assign them to flight levels with a certain amount of vertical separation between them, then they will accurately maintain that separation despite the fact that they are not accurately maintaining true elevation.

---

> flat earthers believe that...

Of course, all of the above is true regardless of whether the Earth is a sphere or a flat disk.